# Installed kubuntu on a usb stick, want to go back to windows

Tags: kubuntu, external-hdd

I am running Windows 8, I installed kubuntu on a usb stick. Now when i remove usb stick i get an error "no such device exists", I want to get rid of kubuntu and this error. I am not linux user so please tell me an easy way to do that. Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you need to set the boot device back to the HDD in the BIOS, but you'd have to add the motherboard make and model if you need specific help with that.

Comment: I am using HP Pavillion g6 1139-tx

Comment: I shall be very grateful to you if you can tell me in detail how to get back everything to normal (windows only)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Insert the Windows 8 Installation Disc in your system’s optical drive, or use a bootable USB for that matter, and make sure you boot your PC using this removable media.

Step 2: On the Install now screen, select Repair your computer.

Step 3: On the next screen, choose Troubleshoot, followed by Advanced options.

Step 4: From Advanced options, launch a command prompt windows, and enter the following command:

**bootrec.exe /fixmbr**

Step 5: Once the command is finished, reboot your computer the normal way, and Windows 8 should load just fine now.